# What are the rules of the Shinobi Code of Conduct?

Tags: naruto

I was watching *Naruto Shippuden* during the Kakashi chronicles, and he mentions that rule 25 is that a Shinobi isn't allowed to cry.

What are the other rules (that have been revealed)?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few more indeed.

> - Rule #04. "A shinobi must always put the mission first."
> - Rule #25. "A shinobi must never show their tears.
> - Rule #??. "A shinobi must see the hidden meanings within the hidden meanings."
> - Rule #??. "A shinobi must follow their commander's instructions."
> - Rule #??. "A shinobi must prepare before it is too late to."
> - Rule #??. "A shinobi must never show any weakness."

There also seem to be war-specific rules

> During the Warring States Period, one of the rules forbade shinobi from revealing their surnames for fear of retaliation outside of combat.

as seen in the [Wikia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shinobi_Rules).

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget the rule that supersedes all rules: protect your comrades!

> ・・・確かに忍者の世界でルールや掟を破る奴はクズ呼ばわりされる・・・　けどな・・・
>   「仲間を大切にしない奴はそれ以上のクズだ」
>
> "*...Tashika ni ninja no sekai de rūru ya okite o yaburu yatsu wa kuzu yobawari sareru... kedo na... nakama o taisetsu ni shinai yatsu wa sore ijou no kuzu da*"

which can be translated as

> "...Certainly, those in the ninja world who break the rules are called trash... but you know... those who don't value their comrades are even  worse trash then that."

or

> "It may be true that in the ninja world, those who break the rules are called trash, but... Those who don't treasure their friends are even worse than trash!!"

Comment: Where did you get this from? Can you provide a source?

Comment: @kuwaly Seems to be a quote from Kakashi:  believe it is also quoted here http://less-real.com/quotes/search/Hatake+Kakashi

Comment: See also http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Shinobi_Rules

Comment: It's Kakashi I think, just after his first test with the bells and pointing out that the exercise was about teamwork and none of them worked together.

Answer (score 1):

Rule 1. Shinobi must always show allegiance to their Kage.

Rule 2. A Shinobi must not value himself but rather adhere to his village's ideals.

Rule 3. hone your reflexes, they often react without you realising it.

Rule 4. A Shinobi must always put the mission first.

Rule 5. A Shinobi must always put his village before himself.

Rule 6. Misdirection is the sharpest blade.

Rule 7. A Shinobi should be able to prevail without fighting, only if there is no other choice but to do so.

Rule 8. A Shinobi must abstain from overindulging in the three vices: sex, alcohol and money.

Rule 9. A Shinobi must always carry out the mission assigned.

Rule 10. There are times when information is more important than lives.

Rule 11. A Shinobi must see the underneath under the underneath.

Rule 12. A Shinobi world is a world of shadows.

Rule 13. Hesitation is death.

Rule 14. When in danger you must not reveal anything involuntarily.

Rule 15. Only through experiencing the confrontation of danger, the transcendence of fear or injury or death can you acknowledge individual personal powers and limitations.

Rule 16. Turn your weaknesses into strengths.

Rule 17. Death to traitors.

Rule 18. A Shinobi must prepare before it is too late to.

Rule 19. Shinobi have no honour, they take their village's honour as their own.

Rule 20. A Shinobi must never question their commander.

Rule 21. The failures or successes of one affect the whole.

Rule 22. A Shinobi must never show attachment.

Rule 23. A Shinobi must endure.

Rule 24. Forgiveness is a luxury.

Rule 25. A Shinobi must never show emotion.

Not sure if these are the actual rules but they seem pretty realistic, so yeah. Here is the source if you wanna check it out: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/10924400/1/Shinobi-Rules-Book

Comment: Considering that there are actually over 100 rules, not end at 25, I doubt this is the actual rules...

Comment: @AkiTanaka Considering the source is hosted on fanfiction.net, yeah not the actual rules...